# Resize & Crop Image Style Lowers Resolution

Tags: media, entities

Whenever I try to implement a "resize & crop" image style on the display of a node in Drupal 7, the image also comes out with a lower resolution than the original file. Any idea why this might be happening or how I can get it to stop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jpeg quality is defined at 75%, this can be changed at /admin/config/media/image-toolkit